# Формулы для полей в MSSQL SERVER

Tags: sql-server, sql

Здраствуйте! Как можно создать вычисляемое поле в mssql server? Например, есть [поле1] и [поле2], которое должно вычисляться, в зависимости, если значение первого поля, например от...до..., то поле2 будет иметь одно значениие, а если поле1= от...до..., то - другое.

Comment: читаем реляционные СУБД, нормальные формы. Непомню в какой из них написано, что нельзя хранить в таблице столбики которые можно вычислить по другим полям той же таблицы. Нужная вам логика должна быть реализована в SQL запросах или в view (если такие имеются в ms sql)

Answer (score 1):

Это вопрос исключительно справочного характера. 
Лучше поискать ответ по книгам, начать можно здесь: [Вычисляемые столбцы](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms191250%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).

А можно еще ответ вот в этом вопросе подсмотреть, если хочется срочно: [SQL Server Calculated Column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4093014/sql-server-calculated-column).

Answer (score 1):

Примерно так:

```
create table t
(
f1 int,
f2 as case when f1 between 1 and 10 then 'one' else 'two' end
)

insert into t(f1) values(2),(12)
select * from t
```